# Prevent BeautifulSoup4 from wrapping XML with <html> and <body> tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I've used bs4 to change some numeric strings of certain elements in the XML, but I don't want the html or body tags to be in the XML when I save the XML as a file.

```
<annotation>
... more stuff here
</annotation>
```

becomes

```
<html>
<body>
<annotation>
... more stuff here
</annotation>
</body>
</html>
```

after loading via

`soup = BeautifulSoup(file_obj.read(), 'lxml')`

I wanted to prettify my XML before saving it, but right now it's just easier to convert soup -> string then throw out the elements I don't want.

Link to one full XML file I'm using: https://gist.github.com/jtara1/4e583160441976e198aba2c7651aaf70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bs4`, you could change your parser engine to `html.parser`:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(file_obj.read(), 'html.parser')
```